# History log on Ticket system database

Tags: database-design

I'm creating a Support Ticket system and it need to have a history of all changes made on that ticket. For example:

- Status change;
- Changed the responsible assistant;
- Sector/Department change;
- Etc..

This is the structure I have at the momment:

[image]

---

I was thinking about it and tought it may be very confusing, or at least not the best option, to create a table structure to store the respective type of change and the `id` from the correspondent table. For example:

```
Type of changes: 
1-> status change;
2-> Department change;
3-> Assistant change; 
[etc]

id  |  ticket_id  |  history_type  |  old_value  |  new_value  |  create_date
1   |      2      |       1        |      3      |      6      |  ....
2   |      7      |       3        |      5      |      2      |  ....
```

The other option I have, is to write plain text, instead of saving the `Id's`, for example:

```
id  |  ticket_id  |  message  |  create_date
1   |     1       |  Status change from 'Open' to 'Closed'  |  ....
2   |     2       |  Assistant change from 'John' to 'Kyle'  |  ....
```

Is there anything wrong with one or another? Or am I missing a important consideration on doing this type of history structure? Or what would be the best option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say that as long as you can guarantee that you (or anyone else) won't change the definitions of the '3','5','6','2' values somewhere down the road, it's not a bad idea.

You'll end up having to do a little more work with the first option to get it into a "User-friendly" view (if that's your end goal), but it seems like INT values (old_value, new_value) would be easier to store than full text values (message).  The main advantage to your second option is that it's easier to read and you don't have to link a few tables together to get the user-friendly version.

Another way I've seen it done (Particularly by Salesforce) is to select which fields you'd like tracked in an object.  Say "status" and "assistant" are your choices.  Salesforce will have a structure as follows:

```
id | ModifiedDate | OldValues                     | New Values
1  | 08/26/2016   | Status: Open, Assistant: John | Status: Closed, Assistant: Kyle
```

This is if at least one value changed.  So even if the assistant hadn't changed, it still displays all field values.

```
  id | ModifiedDate | OldValues                     | New Values
  1  | 08/26/2016   | Status: Open, Assistant: John | Status: Open, Assistant: Kyle
```

It also tracks initial "inserts" as such:

```
id | ModifiedDate | OldValues             | New Values
1  | 08/26/2016   | Status: , Assistant:  | Status: Open, Assistant: John
```

Hope that helps a bit.

Comment: The possible change to be made on the tables "sector" and "status" is to insert new values or modify the name to something better. For example, change "open" to "is open" (just a basic example, of course). But keep the main focus of that status. Nothing like this "Open -> Need files".

Comment: If you think you can guarantee that, then I'd say go for it.  I would (at the very least) implement a system to those "sector" and "status" dates in which you add "START_DATE" and "END_DATE" (or the like) and keep an additional history of when the definitions were made, so that no one down the road loses sight of the original intent of a status.    You want to make sure your code/structure is still usable and easily understood by a complete stranger.

Answer (score 1):

For a database activity, try to focus on the structure of the information.  I would recommend using the keys (could be an ID or it could be some other datum that you are using) in order to have a more easily interpreted structure of data.

Textual data such as `Assistant change from 'John' to 'Kyle'` is harder to keep the structure clean, simply because other data that may need to be reflected in the textual data can easily become more and more complex to interpret.

Of course, for you and other users textual data can be valuable. Rather than storing the text you should create some process in T-SQL or (likely better) through your reporting tools to present the descriptive information.